# Why is the second onSubscribe() call required in my observable sequence?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

It is required that the `onSubscribe()` operator be applied a second time in my sequence of observables, see line: `details.add(myApi.getDetails(h.getId()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()));`. If the `onSubscribe()` operator is not applied, a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` is thrown.

My understanding is that since I'm already applying a `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` operator early in the sequence, that all future subscriptions should happen on the on the `io` scheduler. What is wrong with my understanding? Is this potentially a retrofit beta2 issue since in the below example the `myApi` instance is created via Retrofit?

```
myApi.getHeadlines()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .flatMap(new Func1<Headlines, Observable<HeadlineDetail> {
        @Override
        public Observable<HeadlineDetail> call(Headlines headlines) {
            List<Observable<HeadlineDetail>> details = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Headline h : headlines) {
                  details.add(myApi.getDetails(h.getId()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()));
            }
            return Observable.merge(details);
        }
    })
    .subscribe(...);
```

Dependencies:

- Retrofit Beta 2.0-beta2
- Retrofit rxjava-adapter 2.0-beta2
- rxjava v1.0.14
- rxandroind v1.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subscribeOn` sets the thread the observable starts on, but `observeOn` affects the thread used for downstream operations.  They are "observing" the original observable. You are starting on the background thread, but the switch everything to the main thread.  Try moving your `observeOn` to later in your chain.

See the docs on [`observeOn`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/observeon.html) for more detail.

```
myApi.getHeadlines()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .flatMap(new Func1<Headlines, Observable<HeadlineDetail> {
        @Override
        public Observable<HeadlineDetail> call(Headlines headlines) {
            List<Observable<HeadlineDetail>> details = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Headline h : headlines) {
                  details.add(myApi.getDetails(h.getId()));
            }
            return Observable.merge(details);
        }
    })
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(...);
```